# Calling AsyncTask in fixed intervals

Tags: android-asynctask

I am developing an application which downloads a image from the dropbox folder. However, I want it to download only when a file has been written to that folder. I have written an AsyncTask which perfectly downloads the file. I want to call this AsyncTask every 30 seconds or so. Is it possible to call it inside a loop ? I know Dropbox provides sync API but I found it very tough to develop my application based on that. Instead I made use of the Dropbox core API. Please suggest in ways I can achieve this.

Comment: use a service and the alarmmanager.

Comment: If its not a problem, could you please elaborate it? I don't need the code. But how exactly do I use a service and alarmmanager?

Comment: the alarmmanager will allow you to trigger an action every 30 seconds. This action will be starting a service. this service will be executing your asynctask.

Comment: I saw an example. [link](http://khurramitdeveloper.blogspot.in/2013/06/android-alarm-manager-to-start-service.html). The java file which is nothing but the service that is to be executed again and again, that class will extend the class Service. In my case, it is an AsyncTask. But a class can't extend AsyncTask and Service at the same time right.?

Comment: exactly. there are 2 ways to go about that. Either the service start the asynctask (`new AsyncTask().execute()`) or you can use an `IntentService` instead, which is a service that performs a task on a thread and stops itself afterward.

Comment: Ok. I think I am getting it now. I call the service every 30 secs and the service calls AsyncTask. correct ? One last thing. Can you please tell me in which method of the Service class should I call the AsyncTask? Is it onCreate() or onStartCommand() ?

Comment: onStartCommand. That's where the service is started. You should also stopSelf once the asynctask is finished (in onPostExecute)

Comment: Ok. Will give it a shot

Comment: I tried and the application crashes. I have posted the code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23259321/service-inside-a-asynctask-is-not-running).Please please help me.